# Using Mod correctly Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use mod to round up my lawn area and mowing time. I am stuck and my code isn`t coding lol

I tried a nested if but it wouldn't run either so I commented it out, if anyone can just fix the areas that need amending and not change the code to suit their style, but follow my way. That would help me understand my wrongs better. Thanks

```java
package Tutorial;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tut3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double lgh = 0.0, wdt = 0.0, area = 0.0, mo = 5, mo_time = 0.0;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter lenght in meters\t");
        lgh = key.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter width in meters\t");
        wdt = key.nextDouble();
        area = lgh * wdt;
        mo_time = area / mo;
        
        //add mod to modulate any remaining numbers
        if (mo_time < 60) {
            System.out.printf("\nLawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.0f  mins ", area,
                    (mo_time % 60));
        } else if (mo_time >= 60 && mo_time <= 90) {
            System.out.printf("\n***Lawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.1f hour  %.0f  mins ",area, (mo_time /60  ), (mo_time % 60 ));
        }
            // if time is >=60 use mod to round up in to hours and mins unless time is 60min then time reads 1 hour, not 1 hour 0 mins and so on, if areas sqm is 30.0 round up to 30sqm and so on
            /*if (mo_time % 60 == 0) {
                System.out.printf("\n###Your lawn area = %.2fm2\n\nMowing time %.1f hour", area, (mo_time / 60));
            }*/
        else if (mo_time > 90) {
            System.out.printf("\nLawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.0f hour %.0f  mins \n\nTime to purchase a new lawnmower", area, (mo_time / 60), (mo_time % 60));
        }
        key.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop playing on your computer and procrastinating.  Just go and mow the lawn!!   :-)

Comment: “my code isn`t coding” is not really a problem statement.  What input are you giving your program, and what output are you expecting to see?

Comment: Many thanks all for you comments and help  @user85421 I will reduce those empty lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by this format specifier `Mowing time %.0f hour` which will round of your hour value with no digits after the decimal point. For example:

`lgh = 50.0`, `wdt = 10.0`, So, `area = 500.0`, `mo_time = 500/5 = 100`.

Which will trigger the last else if case. Now, when it will try to print `100/60 = 1.6666666...` to 0 digits after decimal point. It would round up to `2`. You can use [Math.floor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) to get the floor value. That will be `1` in this example.

Also, in your current code, if the `area` is less than `mo`. It will print `0`. So, you can use [Math.ceil()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) to take the ceiling of the minute value.

Here is the modified code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tut3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double lgh = 0.0, wdt = 0.0, area = 0.0, mo = 5, mo_time = 0.0;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter length in meters\t");
        lgh = key.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter width in meters\t");
        wdt = key.nextDouble();
        area = lgh * wdt;
        mo_time = area / mo;

        //add mod to modulate any remaining numbers
        if (mo_time < 60) {
            System.out.printf("\nLawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.0f  mins ", area, Math.ceil(mo_time));
        } else if (mo_time <= 90) {
            System.out.printf("\n***Lawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.0f hour  %.0f  mins ",
                    area, Math.floor(mo_time/60), Math.ceil(mo_time%60));
        } else if (mo_time > 90) {
            System.out.printf("\nLawn area = %.2f m2\n\nMowing time %.0f hour %.0f  mins \n\nTime to purchase a new lawnmower",
                    area, Math.floor(mo_time/60), Math.ceil(mo_time%60));
        }
        key.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Many thanks Rifat for correcting the code, I found when I experimented that if I only used Math.floor once on the 2nd else if, and not use .ceil or .floor anywhere else. The rest of the code would work as supposed to, why ? I also wanted to round up the numbers after the decimal with  (area)  so lgh 10 * wdt 45 = area 450.00m2 to 450m2

Comment: BTW, If you remove floor from first else if it should not work for cases where `mo_time = 90`. For example: `lgh = 45` and `wdt = 10`. @Chip